# Load csv file in neo4j embedded in Java

Tags: java, database, macos, csv, neo4j

I have a neo4j embedded DB in my application and I want to load a .csv file to fill the database. I've managed to create the .csv file in the `/import` folder but when I try to load it, I get a `Couldn't load the external resource at: file:/csv_file.csv`.
I've read it may be something about permissions but I cannot change them since it creates the whole folder structure every time I run my application (I try to change them after creating the file with `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod 777 /path_to_file/csv_file.csv")` but it never works)

This is my code:

```
public void addCSVtoDB() {
    try ( Transaction ignored = graphDb.beginTx();
            Result result = graphDb.execute( "LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM \"file:///csv_file.csv\" AS csvLine\n" )
        {

    }
```

I'm using MacOSX 10.11 so the / are supposed to be allright. Any idea?

Comment: Add this to your conf/neo4j.conf file dbms.security.allow_csv_import_from_file_urls=true

Comment: It's embedded, I don't have any conf file (I think)

Comment: I have configured the embedded database to allow file urls, still got the `couldn't load the external resource at: file:/csv_file.csv` 
I'm doing this to define the database:
`graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory()
       .newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder( databaseDirectory )
       .setConfig( GraphDatabaseSettings.allow_file_urls, "true" )
       .newGraphDatabase();
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I finllay solved it: everywhere it says that the `.csv` files had to be in the /import folder but that doesn't applies to embedded databases. The `path_to_file` is absolute so I put the `.csv` file in my `/users/MY_USER/` folder and made the cypher query as follows:

```
public void addCSVtoDB() {
    try ( Transaction ignored = graphDb.beginTx();
            Result result = graphDb.execute( "LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM \"file:////Users/My_User/csv_file.csv\" AS csvLine\n" )
        {

    }
```